# Interpolating from a Hard Lefschetz class to a Kaehler class

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, smooth-manifolds, kahler-manifolds, differential-forms

Let $X$ be a compact smooth manifold that admits symplectic and Kaehler structures.

There is a paper by Ugarte, Rudyak, Tralle, and Ibanez, showing how the Lefschetz rank can vary along a path of symplectic forms on $X$.  Using this, one can interpolate between Hard Lefschetz symplectic forms and just plain symplectic forms.

There is also a paper by Draghici that constructs on $4$-manifolds a path of cohomology classes that starts in the Kaehler cone and then definitely leaves it.

However, I am having trouble finding results in the literature that would help me to *start* with a Hard Lefschetz symplectic form and then somehow interpolate from that *to* a Kaehler form.  Do people have any experience with this question?  Or know some good resources for further reading on this topic?  Perhaps I am not framing my question in a good way?  Maybe relinquishing control of the Kaehler structures and attempting to *reach* them (instead of starting with them) is a little bit too intractable?